# Box sizing quirk...how to over come padding expanding div

Tags: html, css

In `box-sizing: border-box;` So if then height equals 20px and if you add padding it cuts inside and not make div expand outside but only if it's less than the total height.

How can i make div not gain height even in case where it's total of both opposite side is more than height. I thought the whole point was to finally determine one solid number for dimensions.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Yjym/3/

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of what you have and what you expect please?

Comment: Can you also explain why you want a 20px box with a larger than 20px padding inside it. And I'm not sure what you refer to with "the whole point", but I'm fairly certain it's not meant to solve impossibilities.

Comment: Why? cause if i want to animate height from 0 to something while not touching the padding inside. It can't be done. At 0 height padding remains. Oh i had fiddle on which i was experimenting but i forgot to put it here. ugh..so yea wait gonna make new one.

Comment: Your c-style comment is breaking the .ex selector in your CSS.

Comment: alright blue still was acting up but look at red that's the one i am talking about one with box-sizing.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer If you are animating the height, should you not also animate the padding as well?

Comment: When I delete the comment and click run, the blue box gets taller.

Comment: @ChrisHardie it depends on what is being done there is no shoulds here. If the effects need padding then yea but if not then no. A very general example would be slide in and out effect as in jquery or sub menu animation. Animating padding there would make it look like a bizarre failed experiment.